# Javascript - search and replace specific words

Tags: javascript, regex, dictionary, replace

I would like to create a textbox the user can use to search for Spanish equivalents of English words. But instead of just typing the word, they have to type the whole question.

Example:
User Input: "How do you say Man in Spanish?" Expected Output: "You say Hombre."

I am using a switch statement, since there will be other things the user can ask about. How can I use regex in a switch case to search for the word the user wants to know the meaning of, and replace it with the Spanish equivalent?

I know how to use regex to replace, say, the fifth word of the sentence (in the case above would be "man") with "hombre". But since the user can ask for words other than "man", what can I do to replace the 5th word with one of many spanish words, depending on what the 5th word actually is?

I hope I am being clear enough for you to understand.

This is what I have:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var text;
    var words = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toLowerCase();
    
    switch(words) {
  case "hello":
            text = "Hello, my friend.";
            break;
        case "how do you say xxx in spanish?":
            text = "You say yyy.";
            break;
        default:
        text = "I don't know what you mean...";
    }
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = text;
}

function translate() {
    var str = document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML; 
    var txt = str.replace("yyy","*spanish word*");
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<p>Ask for the Spanish equivalent of an English word.</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text" size="50">
<button onclick="myFunction();translate()">Ask</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

I would like to be able to detect what word the user typed in the place of xxx, and use the Spanish equivalente of that word in the answer, which means I would also need to have a way to tell that man=hombre, woman=mujer, kid=niño...

I am a bit lost on how to achieve this. Any help?

Comment: Are you assuming its always going to be the 5th word that needs to be translated?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to do a split on space, get the fifth word in this way. Then you have 2options in my eyes. Either you hold a database of words and their translations to get them (a lot of work), or you search for an API that does translations and you include it: https://ctrlq.org/code/19909-google-translate-api.

Comment: @Andrew Lohr, Yes, I am assuming that. Any solution that works that way is good enough.

Comment: You can use google cloud translation api

Comment: @mrdeadsven I don't want to translate all possible words. This is just a small project to teach some basic vocabular to kids. I want to have about 20 words in that.

Comment: @Kamesh Chandra, I am looking for something very simple, that I can build myself. It would be good practice for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to require the sentence to be worded exactly like that every time, you can use the expression `/how do you say \w+ in spanish\?/i` to match the input and the expression `/say (\w+)/i` to capture the word to translate.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var text;
    var words = document.getElementById("myInput").value.toLowerCase();
    
    if (words === "hello") {
        text = "Hello, my friend.";
    } else if (words.match(/how do you say \w+ in spanish\?/i)) {
        // matched word is the second element
        var word = words.match(/say (\w+)/i)[1];
        // find the translation in the object
        var translation = lookup[word];
        text = "You say " + translation + ".";
    } else {
        text = "I don't know what you mean...";
    }
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = text;
}

var lookup = {
    hello: "hola",
    goodbye: "adios"
}
```

```html
<p>Ask for the Spanish equivalent of an English word.</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text" size="50">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Ask</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

To translate the word, you could build an object of English words mapped to Spanish words since you said you will only have 20 words total.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This works great. I just have one more question, if you don't mind. Can I use this in a switch statement? I just tried putting everything from `words.match` to `text = "You say " + translation + ".";` in a switch case, and I am not getting any results... Is this not the way to do it?

Comment: The `match` method returns an array, so using a switch statement with it would be very messy. If-else statements are the best way to do this.

Comment: I understand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Since its a small project with minimal translation I would suggest just keeping the words in a object. You can make the English word the key and the Spanish word the value. to get the fifth word you can split on a space and get the fifth element of the returned array.

In the example below you'll also need to add some error handling to handle when the object doesn't have a key with the fifth word

Here is an example:

```js
var trans = {
  "man": "hombre",
  "book": "libro"
}

function translate() {
  var text;
  var words = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  // split returns an array with space as a delimiter
  // then get the 5th element from the array (remember it starts at 0)
  // then turn it to lower case
  var fifthWord = words.split(" ")[4].toLowerCase();
  // use the word as a key for the trans object to return the Spanish value
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "You say: " + trans[fifthWord];
}

document.getElementById("ask").addEventListener("click", translate);
```

```html
<p>Ask for the Spanish equivalent of an English word.</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text" size="50" value="How do you say Man in Spanish">
<button id="ask">Ask</button>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it and this would be perfect if the only purpose of the textbox was to ask for word equivalents. But I want the users to be able to type other things, like "What is your name", How old are you"... and so on. They will get different answers, generated with the switch statement. Is there a way to only cal the function translate() when the sentence pattern (how do you say --- in spanish) is recognized?